# Listagem em sistema de indicação

Tags: php

estou com uma dificuldade.
Estou criando um sistema de indicação em PHP e estou com dificuldade para listar os clientes e a quantidade de indicações que ele fez.
O sistema tem duas tabelas, a tabela 'clientes' que é onde se encontra os dados do mesmo junto ao código de indicação dele gerado automaticamente, e a tabela 'indicados' onde nela se encontra o id do cliente que acabou de se cadastrar e o código da pessoa que o indicou.
Agora eu estou sem saber qual logica utilizar para fazer a listagem do cliente que tem mais indicados.

[image: Tabela clientes]

[image: Tabela indicados]

Fiz uma tentativa, mas ainda não deu muito certo.

```
<?php
                    $PDO = conectar();
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes,indicados WHERE cod_cli=codcli_indic ORDER BY id_cli ASC";
                    $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    while($resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        foreach($resultado as $user){
                            $qtd = count($user['codcli_indic']);
                        echo "
                        <tr>
                        <td>".$user['id_cli']."</td>
                        <td>".$user['nome_cli']."</td>
                        <td>".$user['loja_cli']."</td>
                        <td>".$qtd."</td>
                    </tr>
                        ";}
                    }
                ?>
```

O resultado ficou assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mauricio indicou 2 pessoas, então ali em indicados deveria aparecer 2 e não aparecer duas vezes Mauricio na tabela.

Bom pessoal, tentei diversas formas e cheguei a um resultado satisfatório, vou deixar aqui como ficou o código, caso alguém tenha a mesma dificuldade.

```
<?php
                    $PDO = conectar();

                    $sql = "SELECT *, count(*) as count FROM clientes,indicados WHERE cod_cli=codcli_indic GROUP BY codcli_indic";

                    $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    //$qtd = count($resultado);


                   foreach($resultado as $user){
                       if ($user['cod_cli'] == $user['codcli_indic']){
                        $qtd = count($user['id_indic']);
                       }


                        echo "
                        <tr>
                        <td>".$user['id_cli']."</td>
                        <td>".$user['nome_cli']."</td>
                        <td>".$user['loja_cli']."</td>
                        <td>".$user['count']."</td>
                    </tr>
                        ";
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar as estruturas das tabelas?

Comment: Perdão, esqueci de incluir

Comment: As tabelas possuem chave estrangeira?

Comment: Sua pergunta não está bem clara, mas ve se ajuda `select max(sum), nome_cli from (Select count(c.id_cli) as sum, c.nome_cli from clientes c join indicados i on i.idcli_indic = c.id_cli group by c.id_cli, c.nome_cli)`

Comment: Editei com um teste que fiz, mas não deu muito certo.

Answer (score 0):

Pois então, no seu caso, acho que seria bom você usar um `INNER JOIN`, para que seja o caso de haver um resultado positivo em sua query... Que ficaria no caso assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clientes t1
INNER JOIN indicados t2
ON t1.cod_cli = t2.codcli_indic
ORDER BY t1.id_cli ASC
```

Sugerindo a você também dar uma lida na ilustração de como ocorre as consultas [JOINS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins.aspx) para que haja um maior entendimento sobre tais consultas! :)

---

A duplicação de resultados se deve ao fato de ter um **foreach** dentro de um **while**, onde não tem a mínima necessidade, sendo que seu código poderá ficar assim:

```
while($resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $qtd = count($resultado['codcli_indic']);
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td>".$resultado['id_cli']."</td>
    <td>".$resultado['nome_cli']."</td>
    <td>".$resultado['loja_cli']."</td>
    <td>".$qtd."</td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
```

Comment: Ainda assim continua aparecendo a repetição da coluna, mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu vi onde você errou e arrumei o teu código, tente agora... Visto que você não necessita ter um `foreach` dentro de um `while`, pois o **while** já irá fazer o loop de resultado e se colocar o **foreach** ele irá duplicar esses resultados! :)

Comment: A repetição desapareceu, muito obrigado!! Agora, os números de indicados está com o valor 1 para os dois usuários, sendo que um deles tem dois indicados

Comment: Você já tentou fazer o `count()` apenas do `$resultado`? Pois dentro da query ele já faz a verificação, e ali você está fazendo a contagem apenas de **1 coluna**. Tente fazer o seu **count()** apenas do **$resultado** e retorne aqui para demais dúvidas! :)

Comment: Tentei sim, quando faço o count apenas do $resultado, ele apresenta o numero 2 em ambos os usuários :(